# Command to find current enum depth?

Tags: macros, enumerate, counters

I was wondering if there was a command to find what at what depth of the `enum` counter (i.e. `enumi`, `enumii`, etc.) a command was at compile time.  I'm attempting to create a `\question` command. What I have so far:

```
\newcommand{\question}[2][\value{enumi}+1]{\setcounter{enumi}{#1-1} \item \textbf{#2}}
```

Which works great for the first level (Note: requires the `calc` package). What I'm looking for is a command (or series of commands) to replace the `\value{enumi}+1` with whatever the current depth is so that something like:

```
\begin{enumerate}
   \question{Whatever}
   \question[10]{Blah}
      \begin{enumerate}
         \question[2]{Stuff}
      \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

would produce output like:

```
1. Whatever
10. Blah
   (b). Stuff
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to know the depth of the current `enumerate` to modify the appropriate counter; `\@enumdepth` holds the current enumeration nesting depth:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\question}[2][\value{enum\romannumeral\@enumdepth}+1]{\setcounter{enum\romannumeral\@enumdepth
}{#1-1} \item \textbf{#2}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
   \question{Whatever}
   \question[10]{Blah}
      \begin{enumerate}
         \question[2]{Stuff}
        \begin{enumerate}
           \question[6]{Other stuff}
        \end{enumerate}
      \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You beat me to it. Two notes: 1) You don't need `\the` after `\romannumeral` as it automatically looks for a number; 2) I'd include the `enum\romannumeral\@enumdepth` in the default for the optional argument as well as in the command body.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't able to find anything on `\@enumdepth` when I was searching (although I can now obviously find plenty).

Comment: You can find the definition `\newcount\@enumdepth \@enumdepth = 0` in the LaTeX kernel. Run `texdoc source2e` in a terminal, and search for `\@enumdepth`.