# Indexing showing "enumerate" counter instead of page

Tags: indexing

The default index created by `makeidx` shows the list of the indexed entries and the pages of the corresponding occurrences.

I need to index many words that appear many times in just a few pages (inside a long `enumerate` environment), so it doesn't make sense to show the pages where they occur.
Instead I'd like to show, for each indexed key, its occurrences inside the `enumerate` environment (i.e. the values of the `enumerate` counter corresponding to items in which the key appears).

Is it possible to do that?

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
 \item The One Ring can be destroyed only in Mordor.
 \index{One Ring}
 \index{Mordor}
 
 \item Sauron's fortress is Barad-d\^{u}r, which is located in Mordor.
 \index{Sauron}
 \index{Barad-d\^{u}r}
 \index{Mordor}
 
 \item The One Ring belongs to Sauron.
 \index{One Ring}
 \index{Sauron}
\end{enumerate}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

This is what is shown in the pdf:

> 1. The One Ring can be destroyed only in Mordor.
> 2. Sauron’s fortress is Barad-dur, which is located in Mordor.
> 3. The One Ring belongs to Sauron.
>
> **Index**
>
> Barad-dur, 1
>
> Mordor, 1
>
> One Ring, 1
>
> Sauron, 1

But I'd like the index to be:

> Barad-dur, 2
>
> Mordor, 1, 2
>
> One Ring, 1, 3
>
> Sauron, 2, 3

Comment: It is certainly possible, although I'm not sure if it is advisable.  In any case, please provide a MWE so we can play with it and suggest what you can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution Idea**

We note that the entries for index are made by the `\index` command. Further investigation shows that actual low level writings to the `.idx` file are done by the `\@wrindex` command in `latex.ltx`. This `\@wrindex` uses `\thepage` to write the page numbers which
are eventually used in the index entries.

So, we hack the `\@wrindex` command and use  `\theenumi` in place of `\thepage`.

**The Solution**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeatletter
\def\@wrindex#1{%
   \protected@write\@indexfile{}%
      {\string\indexentry{#1}{\theenumi}}
      \endgroup
      \@esphack}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
 \item The One Ring can be destroyed only in Mordor.
 \index{One Ring}
 \index{Mordor}

 \item Sauron's fortress is Barad-d\^{u}r, which is located in Mordor.
 \index{Sauron}
 \index{Barad-d\^{u}r}
 \index{Mordor}

 \item The One Ring belongs to Sauron.
 \index{One Ring}
 \index{Sauron}
\end{enumerate}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

**Limitation**

Only the first level of enumeration (`\enumi`) has been used. Should you want otherwise, please see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27576/command-to-find-current-enum-depth) to improve the solution to use other (current sublevel) levels
of enumeration.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use [`glossaries`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries). You need at least version 4.02 for the following example to work:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[index,counter=enumi,nomain]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newterm{duck}
\newterm{arara}
\newterm{cat}
\newterm{zebra}
\newterm{aardvark}
\newterm{goose}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item A \gls{duck} and a \gls{zebra} went to tea with the \gls{arara}.

\item A \gls{zebra}.

\item More \glspl{zebra}.

\item Index without producing text\glsadd{cat}.

\item Now with some text: \gls{cat}.

\item An \gls{aardvark} met a \gls{duck}.

\item \Gls{duck}, \gls{duck}, \gls{goose}.
\end{enumerate}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of resulting documnt]