# `enumdepth` and `ifthenelse`

Tags: enumerate, ifthenelse

I would like to generate text based on my current depth of the enumeration. After a little search, I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27578/143716). It seems `ifthenelse` is not respecting `enumdepth` properly. Am I doing something wrong?

Working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand{\curdepth}[1] %
               { 
                  \ifthenelse{\equal{\@enumdepth}{1}}
                  {\small Current counter is \theenumi}
                  {\small Current counter is \theenumi~(\theenumii)}
               }

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item This is the first item in the list. \curdepth

\item Sample
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item This is the first item in the list. \curdepth

  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The output is:

```
1. This is the first item in the list. Current counter is 1 ()
2. Sample
(a) This is the first item in the list. Current counter is 2 (a)
```

The expected output is:

```
1. This is the first item in the list. Current counter is 1
2. Sample
(a) This is the first item in the list. Current counter is 2 (a)
```

-- Mike

Comment: Can you provide a complete, compiling, working example?

Comment: you should always provide a full example, for example have you used this code at a point where `@` may be used in command names (eg inside a package file)

Comment: Edited the original post and added working example!

Comment: I agree with both above comments. I just adding that if you use this code in your preamble you possibly need to put the command using it inside `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`

Comment: @koleygr, modifying the line to `\makeatletter\@enumdepth\makeatother` is not making change! Do I need to use them (these two commands) some-where-else? Adding it at the point where `\curdepth` is called also doesnt help! Sorry if I am doing something stupid!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `\@enumdepth` is equal to a TeX count, you should add `\the` to make it work (and, of course, makeat...).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\curdepth}[1]{ 
                  \ifthenelse{\equal{\the\@enumdepth}{1}}
                  {\small Current counter is \theenumi}
                  {\small Current counter is \theenumi~(\theenumii)}
               }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item This is the first item in the list. \curdepth

\item Sample
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item This is the first item in the list. \curdepth

  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: WOW!!! Thanks @TeXnician(https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/124577/texnician) and @Michael Palmer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/117431/michael-palmer). Its working like a charm... I didnt think of `\the`, as I thought `@enumdepth` is not a counter, so `\the` is not necessary!

Comment: @MikeV.D.C. It is no counter, it is a TeX count register (that's more basic than a counter). If you encounter such a problem in future, you can try using `\show\@enumdepth` (or whatever) to see what it really is.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\curdepth[1]{\small Current counter is \theenumi%
    \ifnum\@enumdepth>\@ne ~(\theenumii)\fi}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Way too simple... ;)

Answer (score 1):

By default, `\ifthenelse` performs numeric tests, so `\@enumdepth=1` is sufficient; the `\equal` test is about strings.

You also need to surround the `\newcommand` with `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, because you need to use a macro with `@` in its name.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\curdepth}[1]{% <-- don't forget
  \ifthenelse{\@enumdepth=1}
    {\small Current counter is \theenumi}
    {\small Current counter is \theenumi~(\theenumii)}% <-- don't forget
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item This is the first item in the list. \curdepth

\item Sample
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item This is the first item in the list. \curdepth

  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```